# How to consume REST in C# including PUT, POST and DELETE?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, http, rest

I have a REST webservice that I need to consume in C#. I need support for more than just GET requests though. I need everything that is done by REST including GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE. What is the best way of interfacing with this? I do not see anything for HTTPRequest to be able to do POST or anything other than GET unless you construct your own headers(which I prefer not to)

Is there some easy and lightweight way to fully consume REST webservices in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the series of screencasts on WCF REST up on Channel 9:

http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/REST%20Starter%20Kit%20endpoint%20screencasts/

There's a great one amongst those called [Consuming REST services with HttpClient](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Consuming-REST-services-with-HttpClient/) which should give you a nice step-by-step instruction on how to do all of this.

Also check out the [WCF REST Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx) on MSDN for more articles, blog posts, and tutorial on WCF and REST.

Comment: +1 for using the HttpClient.  I also did some blog posts here on the subject http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2009/12/08/why-the-microsoft-http-library-is-awesome/

Answer (score 5):

The HttpClient in the Microsoft.Http namespace that comes with the [WCF Rest Starter kit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644) is very helpful.

Aaron Skonnard from Pluralsight created several articles and screencasts highlighting the HttpClient.

- [Screencast: Consuming REST Services
  with HttpClient](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2009/03/16/screencast-consuming-rest-services-with-httpclient.aspx)
- [A myriad of
  messaging processing options with
  HttpClient](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2009/03/17/a-myriad-of-messaging-processing-options-with-httpclient.aspx) (documents Get, Post, Put, Delete, Head, etc.)

There are several more resources that he posted to the [Pluralsight blog in March 2009](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2009/03.aspx) covering the HttpClient.

Comment: Pluralsight links are gone.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [REST Starter Kit](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=aspnet&title=WCF%20REST&referringTitle=Home) on CodePlex.

Answer (score 3):

HTTPRequest is the request currently processed in a ASP app.

To make outboud HTTP REST requests, use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. It has properties like [Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx) (POST, PUT, DELETE) and you can write your payload into the request stream returned by [GetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getrequeststream.aspx) (or its async counterpart for high performance).