# What assembly is HttpClient stored in

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I want to use the `HttpClient` class from the WCF Rest Service to create a client to call rest 
 services.  I heard it was rolled into .net  4.0 but don't know the assembly it's stored in.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is new in .NET 4.5.

> "Supported in: 4.5"

If you're on .NET 4.5, it will be in the System.Net.Http assembly.

Answer (score 12):

While you are waiting for .net 4.5 to roll out, you can get a 4.0 version from Nuget. http://nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http

Answer (score 4):

Just [see the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Namespace: System.Net.Http
>   Assembly: System.Net.Http (in
>   **System.Net.Http.dll**)

Answer (score 0):

The WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2 includes a set of classes designed to simplify interaction with REST web services. The communications are performed using the **HttpClient** class with the help of other types from the Microsoft.Http namespace. These types can be found in the Microsoft.Http.dll assembly located in the Assemblies folder of the starter kit.


link 1: [Introduction to the HttpClient](http://alexmg.com/post/2009/04/07/Introduction-to-the-HttpClient.aspx)

link 2: [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx)

link 3: [How to consume REST in C# including PUT, POST and DELETE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517825/how-to-consume-rest-in-c-sharp-including-put-post-and-delete)

Comment: That library has been deprecated and is replaced by the one here http://nuget.org/List/Packages/HttpClient