# The type or namespace 'HttpClient' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net

I am losing my mind over this reference error. I've added the `Microsoft.Net.Http` Nuget package, made sure the `System.Net.Http` reference is added to the page, imported the `System.Net.Http` namespace to the class. Nothing. I even went as far as to recreate the project from scratch using a blank template.

Can someone offer some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778773/what-assembly-is-httpclient-stored-in

Comment: Good question. I'm targeting 4.6.1.

Comment: No issues here. Visual Studio 2015 Express, installed latest stable 4.0.0 System.Net.Http, then using System.Net.Http;, then HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); - all working fine. Project using .Net 4.5

Comment: Try type in any method body inside your class: System.Net.Http. and after the last dot, does it show by the InteliSense?

Comment: What's the namespace of the class you've created? I've accidentally had this issue before when there was a name clash.

Comment: @Balah: namespace is {Project}.App_Code. I've tried changing that as well to no avail.

Comment: @st_stefanov: Interestingly I have another very similar solution where this works just fine. Right now Intellisense is not giving me the the HttpClient option but it was before I recreated the project.

Comment: After adding reference to that class in your project, when you bring up its' properties, what path does it show? And is Copy Local true or false?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: See below please. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if you have already tried this, but:

All I did was add the System.Net.Http in the project references.

In the Project Explorer, right click references -> add reference, then tick the relevant checkbox from the list of dlls and click OK

Comment: And when I have added System.Net.Http to my references and it still tells me to add it to my references, what then?

Answer (score 12):

In my visual studio 2017 Xamarin.forms project I had the same problem.
If I right click my solution, there is the
"Manage NuGet packages..."
If I select it, in the "Browse", I look for "System.net"
I selected the found item, [image]
checked the checkboxes for the project and clicked "Install"

Answer (score 8):

Use the fully qualified name:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = ....
}
```

Instead of:

```
using System.Net.Http
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        HttpClient client = ...
    }
}
```

This should show you what issue you are having. If it is name conflict...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that too but still coming up with error ... does not exist int he namespace 'System.Net.Http.' :(

Comment: Ok, in this case I need to ask you to share the code with us to be able to help you.

Comment: It's proprietary so I can't do that, sorry. But easy enough to reproduce: using system.net.http; namespace test { public class test { var client = new HttpClient(); } }

Comment: Yeah, I mean, make a blank project, get the DLL via NuGet manager and reference it. If you have the issue then share that code that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the attempts at figuring this out. I just copied in another project in which this was working like it should, deleted all classes, and copied in classes from the non-working project. Wish I knew what was really going on but I can't afford to burn any more time on this. :(

Answer (score 8):

If targetting 4.6.2 or above, ignore whatever nuget packages are installed as long as they are installed because they are dependencies of your existing references.

Then, open the .csproj files that reference the dll and remove any specific version association so the reference now looks like this (older csproj format):

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
```

Previously, my config looked something like this:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.3\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

This will strongly encourage msbuild to use the version in the GAC for the targetted framework. In my case I was targetting 4.7.2 and it used that version when it warned of a conflict in versions due to the nuget packages.

Comment: Genius!
How did you diagnose this issue? Couldn't have solved it myself. 
For me, the project was building fine locally but it was throwing the same error on the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:**

Right click on your namespace ie, project -> Add -> Add Nuget Packages.

**Step 2:**

Search for system.net.http and Add Package.

**Step 3:**

Add `using System.Net.Http;` to your cs class.

Answer (score 2):

For people that are updating to **.NET 8**, a breaking change is that: 
**"Implicit using for System.Net.Http no longer added"**.

So you need to explicitly use the namespace:

```
using System.Net.Http
```

Read more about the change here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/implicit-global-using-netfx

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to upgrade Visual Studio Professional 2017 from 15.x.y to 15.9.18.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already added the `Microsoft.Net.Http` Nuget package, there must be an exclamation mark next to System.Net.Http in your project references as below: 
[image]

You need to remove this and again: right click it and select 'Remove' and now add it again from the list of dlls

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your build is .net 4.5 and up.  I was running .net 4.0 and that library will not work.  You need to move your solution to 4.5.  Then install with Nuget.